# working with dataset containing Persian records

Tags: python, dataset, farsi

am working on a data set containing Persian records, I installed Persian and unicodcsv, but still have this error.

```
df = pd.read_csv('datasets\NSIA.Individuals.csv')
df.head()
```

the error I get is:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 8-9: malformed \N character escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as shown from the error is not the file content but rather the path itself, I'm guessing your using windows and the combination **"\N"** is problematic because its an escape character, you can read more about escape characters in the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

You can do the following to the path and it will solve the above problem:

```
df = pd.read_csv('datasets\\NSIA.Individuals.csv')
```

another approach is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'datasets\NSIA.Individuals.csv')
```

There might be problem with the content afterward though.

Comment: What are the `'''` for?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile If for instance the string slide from 1 line (appearance wise) then this `'''<str>'''` is a way to jump lines and the reading will still be valid and nice

Comment: I'm confused, I don't expect people to use `'''` everywhere **just in case** there happens to be a longer string **at some point in the future**. If it's a single line, `'` is fine.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Changed it, but it shouldn't make you confused everyone has their on conventions